# Sperating (encapsulating) Pages Using Dialogs In PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, pyqt6

I am creating GUI for an app using PyQt... I am currently using the desginer for the basics and coding the more complex stuff... And I thought it would be nice to separate things a bit. So I thought about creating the sign-up and login pages as dialogs, and then just pop them up / mount them as widgets in the app's mainwindow...

The other approach I know of, is fully creating them in a different page using a QStackedWidget, but I feel like it burdens the entire application, because it overflows it with widgets which have the same hierarchy, while I'd prefer it to be more encapsulated... Like mounting complete-page-widgets in different pages of QStackedWidget instead of just creating all of the objects in it (which makes me use prefixes for each page that disgust me...).

So I want to know the correct approach, and any suggestions will be welcomed.

edit_1:

snippet of my current code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
...
    self.ui.p2_lw_filetable.setWordWrap(True)
    self.ui.p2_lw_filetable.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(64,64))
    self.ui.p2_lw_filetable.setFlow(QtWidgets.QListWidget.Flow.LeftToRight)
    self.ui.p2_lw_filetable.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.ResizeMode.Adjust)
    self.ui.p2_lw_filetable.setLayoutMode(QtWidgets.QListView.LayoutMode.Batched)
    self.ui.p2_lw_filetable.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.ViewMode.IconMode)
...
```

How I want it to be:

```
class Page2(QWidget):
...


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
...
    self.page2 = Page2()
    self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page2)
...
```

Basically I want to encapsulate each page as a widget, so it can be defined and setted up on its own, and then add it to the mainwindow in its respectable place in the main QStackedWidget.

By that I hope to achieve clearer code,
but I am not sure if that's the right way to do that.

The Bottom Line:
I need the right way for separating the hierarchy of the widgets in my ui and making it more modular.

An example of how I would like them to be:
`self.ui.page2.button...` 
instead of the prefix way: `self.ui.page2_button`...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "encapsulating"? Also, be aware that QDialog is intended (and implemented) as a top level widget, and adding it to a QStackedWidget is not only pointless and useless, but also *wrong* (despite some terrible YouTube tutorials suggest). Finally, consider looking into QWizard.

Comment: I updated the question with more details.

Comment: In order to do that you normally need to create separate classes for each "page type", which is fundamentally what you're suggesting in your second code snippet. Note that you can get rid of the `self.ui` namespace and just use `self` if you use multiple inheritance (see [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)) or functions provided by the uic module in PyQt (not available in PySide) like `loadUi`: `self.ui.button` would become `self.button`, meaning that you'll also be able to have something like `self.page2.button` instead of `self.ui.page2.button`.